# Grouping on each set of Combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some data in the SQL Fiddle example (TestTable). What I would ultimately like is to calculate the sum of Value for each combination of name,Value (the OutPut Table shows the ideal output, i.e. a label that can be used in a group by on the expanded input data to calculate the sum).

I have tried cross joining with different row_number() etc. but can't get to the desired answer. I think it will be possible via stored procedure but would like to avoid that if possible.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1508b/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [YEAR] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VALUE] [float] NOT NULL
)

;

INSERT INTO TestTable
    ([Year], [Name], [Value])
VALUES
    (2009, 'ALFRED', 343.33),
    (2009, 'ALFRED', 33.23),
    (2009, 'ALFRED', 40.34),
    (2009, 'TOM', 33.3),
    (2009, 'TOM', 34.3),
    (2009, 'JULIE', 90),
    (2009, 'JULIE', 33)
;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OutputTable](
    [GROUPID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [YEAR] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VALUE] [float] NOT NULL
)
;


INSERT INTO OutPutTable
    ([GroupID], [Year], [Name], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 2009, 'ALFRED', 343.33),
    (1, 2009, 'TOM', 33.3),
    (1, 2009, 'JULIE', 90),
    (2, 2009, 'ALFRED', 343.33),
    (2, 2009, 'TOM', 33.3),
    (2, 2009, 'JULIE', 33),
    (3, 2009, 'ALFRED', 343.33),
    (3, 2009, 'TOM', 34.4),
    (3, 2009, 'JULIE', 90),
    (4, 2009, 'ALFRED', 343.33),
    (4, 2009, 'TOM', 34.3),
    (4, 2009, 'JULIE', 33),
    (5, 2009, 'ALFRED', 33.23),
    (5, 2009, 'TOM', 33.3),
    (5, 2009, 'JULIE', 90),
    (6, 2009, 'ALFRED', 33.23),
    (6, 2009, 'TOM', 33.3),
    (6, 2009, 'JULIE', 33),
    (7, 2009, 'ALFRED', 33.23),
    (7, 2009, 'TOM', 34.4),
    (7, 2009, 'JULIE', 90),
    (8, 2009, 'ALFRED', 33.23),
    (8, 2009, 'TOM', 34.3),
    (8, 2009, 'JULIE', 33),
    (9, 2009, 'ALFRED', 40.34),
    (9, 2009, 'TOM', 33.3),
    (9, 2009, 'JULIE', 90),
    (10, 2009, 'ALFRED', 40.34),
    (10, 2009, 'TOM', 33.3),
    (10, 2009, 'JULIE', 33),
    (11, 2009, 'ALFRED', 40.34),
    (11, 2009, 'TOM', 34.4),
    (11, 2009, 'JULIE', 90),
    (12, 2009, 'ALFRED', 40.34),
    (12, 2009, 'TOM', 34.3),
    (12, 2009, 'JULIE', 33)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select groupid,sum(value) from OutputTable group by groupid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1508b/3/0)**:

```
| groupid |                    |
|---------|--------------------|
|       1 |             466.63 |
|       2 |             409.63 |
|       3 | 467.72999999999996 |
|       4 |             410.63 |
|       5 |             156.53 |
|       6 |              99.53 |
|       7 |             157.63 |
|       8 |             100.53 |
|       9 |             163.64 |
|      10 |             106.64 |
|      11 |             164.74 |
|      12 |             107.64 |
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/10/11/grouping-sets-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: we didn't get you could you just show input table with data and expected result table

Comment: Input table is TestTable above and output table is as above.